# Angular JS - template de uma directiva com ng-model não funciona dentro de ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives, switch

Para ficar mais dinâmica minha directiva resolvi incluir o campo categoria que faz a seleção do tipo de template a ser exibido. Como é apenas um select pensei em usar o ng-switch invés de vários arquivos html.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/fnCJj15XJN1kQvKq1OtZ?p=preview

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<sg-combo 
  selected-item="selectedItem" categoria="filtro">
</sg-combo>

{{selectedItem}}
```

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedItem = null;
    $scope.$watch('selectedItem',function(item){
    if (item != null){
        alert(item.nome); // Não exibe o alert qdo está com o switch
    }
  })
});

app.directive('sgCombo', function(){
    function link(scope, elem, attrs){    
            scope.dados = [
                {'codigo':1, 'nome':'teste1'},
                {'codigo':2, 'nome':'teste2'},
                {'codigo':3, 'nome':'teste3'}
            ];
    }

    return {
            restrict: 'E',          
        scope: {            
            selectedItem: '=',            
            categoria: '@'            
        },
        link: link,
        templateUrl:"sg-combo.html"
    }
})
```

**sg-combo.html**

```
<div ng-switch="categoria">
  <div ng-switch-when="filtro" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
     <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">
        <label>{{label}}</label>
        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.nome for item in dados" class="form-control"></select>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when="anexo" class="col-sm-4 control-label">
     <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">
        <label>{{label}}</label>
        <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.nome for item in dados" class="form-control"></select>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entrei no seu Plunker e observei que está funcionando sim.

Ajustei alguns pontos no seu projeto e obtive o resultado esperado:

Segue o o Plunker Alterado: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Sc68XBrT745WM5Jbn47Y?p=preview)

Basicamente as alterações foram:

Colocar um identificador (titulo) nas templates, para saber que o switch funcionou

```
 <div ng-switch-when="filtro" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Filtro
 <div ng-switch-when="anexo" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Anexo
```

Modifiquei o index para trazer as categorias diferentes de template:

```
<sg-combo selected-item="selectedItem" categoria="filtro"></sg-combo>
{{selectedItem}}

<sg-combo selected-item="selectedItem2" categoria="anexo"></sg-combo>
{{selectedItem2}}
```

Modifique io seu teste do `watch`uma vez que o item é um objeto (não nulo) e ele estava entrando no if, nulo é o valor do objeto...

```
$scope.selectedItem = {value:null};
$scope.selectedItem2 = {value:null};
$scope.$watch('selectedItem',function(item){
    if (item.value !== null) { /* code */ }

$scope.$watch('selectedItem2',function(item){
    if (item.value !== null) { /* code */ }
}
```

Abraço !

Comment: obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente